# How to show lyrics embedded in mp3 file?

Tags: mpv

My music collection has lyrics saved in mp3 files in *lyrics-eng* tag.
Sometimes I want to see them when playing . How can I get that functionality? `show-text` command might help , but I don't know how to show value of an mp3 tag. `l show-text "${lyrics-eng}"` and pressing l shows `error`.